# Bootstrap Radio Selection if in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to use this bootstrap radio selection with if in javascript. Like if option1 is true, do this... How can I afford this?

```
<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
    <label>Selection</label>
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-secondary">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Active
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-secondary">
            <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Radio
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Radio
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener('click', function() {

        if (i == 0)
            console.log('function1');
        else if (i == 1)
            console.log('function2');
        else
            console.log('function3');
    });
}
```

Change `console.log()`s with desired functions.

Another option using ids.

```
var inp1 = document.getElementById('option1');
var inp2 = document.getElementById('option2');
var inp3 = document.getElementById('option3');
var inputs = [inp1, inp2, inp3];

...
```

Rest is the same.

Comment: Thank you I will try that out. If I use multiple input elements on the site I should use getelementbyid?